# DropDown to select data from MS SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, dropdown, adventureworks

I'm trying to make a PHP web application display the data from specific `Countries` from a dropdown but I can't figure it out how to use the WHERE [Column] = [Value1, Value2, Value3] on a PHP dropdown.

I'm using the `"Adventure Works 2014 Full Database Backup"` for test purpose.

```
<html>
</body>
<!-- form for tower selection -->
<form action="test20.php" method="POST">
Please select the tower you are about to work on. </br></br>
<select name="TowerSelect"><option> Choose </option>
<?php
$serverName = 'SERVERNAME';
$uid = 'USERNAME';
$pwd = 'PASSWORD';
$databaseName = 'AdWorks';

$connectionInfo = array( 'UID'=>$uid,
                        'PWD'=>$pwd,
                        'Database'=>$databaseName);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);
if($conn){
    echo '';
}else{
    echo 'Connection failure<br />';
die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));
}
$sql = "SELECT BusinessEntityID, FirstName FROM dbo.vKelvin WHERE CountryRegionName = 'United States'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execut query");
while ($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

    echo "<option value=";
    echo $data['BusinessEntityID'];
    echo ">";
    echo $data['BusinessEntityID']; 
    echo "</option>";
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Select Tower">
</select></br></br>
</form>
</body></html>
<?php
if(empty($_POST['TowerSelect'])){     
    $_SESSION['tower'] = ''; 
} else {  
    $_SESSION['tower'] = $_POST['TowerSelect']; 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo $_SESSION['tower'];
    echo "  selected. </p>";
    echo('<td>'.$row['BusinessEntityID'].'</td><td>'.$row['FirstName'].'</td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: What are you asking for?  Are you asking how to use the $_POST results from an HTML form select element in your SQL SELECT query?  I don't see a "dropdown" (I'm assuming <select></select>) anywhere in your code.  At the very least, we seem to be missing the code something comes from... then that something is used in the posted code (I think) and that's failing?

Comment: Just updated my code, would like to display the selected into a table

Comment: In my code when I select a `BusinessEntityID` from the dropdown I do get the " **number ID** selected." but I dont the the rest `echo('<td>'.$row['BusinessEntityID'].'</td><td>'.$row['FirstName'].'</td></tr>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have this fixed.  There were a number of problems with the code.  You were referencing a $row but there was no SQL query that would have resulted in a $row, you were trying to post data after the closing HTML tag, you were trying to create rows for a table without declaring the table, and a few other things.  Some of this was probably a result of quickly creating the test case.  No problem.  Try this...

```
<?php
$serverName = 'SERVERNAME';
$uid = 'USERNAME';
$pwd = 'PASSWORD';
$databaseName = 'AdWorks';
$connectionInfo = array( 'UID'=>$uid,'PWD'=>$pwd,'Database'=>$databaseName);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);
if($conn){echo '';}else{echo 'Connection failure<br />';die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));}

?><html><body>
<!-- form for tower selection -->
<form action="test20.php" method="POST">
Please select the tower you are about to work on. </br></br>
<select name="TowerSelect"><option> Choose </option>
<?php

$sql = "SELECT BusinessEntityID, FirstName FROM dbo.vKelvin WHERE CountryRegionName = 'United States'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execut query");
while ($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo '<option value="'.$data['BusinessEntityID'].'">';
    echo $data['BusinessEntityID']; 
    echo "</option>";
}

?><input type="submit" value="Select Tower">
</select></br></br>
</form>
<table cols="3" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<?php

if(empty($_POST['TowerSelect'])){     
    $_SESSION['tower'] = ''; 
} else {  
    $sql = "SELECT BusinessEntityID, FirstName FROM dbo.vKelvin WHERE BusinessEntityID = '".$_POST['TowerSelect']."'";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execut query");
    while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $_SESSION['tower'] = $_POST['TowerSelect']; 
        echo '<tr><td>'.$_SESSION['tower'].'  selected.</td>';
        echo     '<td>'.$row['BusinessEntityID'].'</td>';
        echo     '<td>'.$row['FirstName'].'</td></tr>';
    }
}

?></table></body></html>
```

**Note:** Though not important to answer your question, it is a best practice to use PDO and bound paramters when making database calls to protect yourself against SQL injection and other nasties.  I recommend you look into it to protect your database.  Cheers!

Comment: I guess my limit PHP knowledge is the issue, this code works perfect, the only thing I'm now having is that my dropdown should only display unique values, by now I have **Canada** twice, **USA** 4 times, etc. `SELECT DISTINCT` maybe?

Comment: Correct.  Check out [this short tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the solution, my select was wrong

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT CountryRegionName FROM dbo.vKelvin ORDER BY CountryRegionName";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execut query");
while ($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo '<option value="'.$data['CountryRegionName'].'">';
echo $data['CountryRegionName']; 
echo "</option>";
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
if(empty($_POST['TowerSelect'])){     
    $_SESSION['tower'] = ''; 
} else {  
    $sql = "SELECT BusinessEntityID, FirstName FROM dbo.vKelvin WHERE BusinessEntityID = '".$_POST['TowerSelect']."'";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql) or die("Couldn't execut query");
    while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $_SESSION['tower'] = $_POST['TowerSelect']; 
        echo '<tr><td>'.$_SESSION['tower'].'  selected.</td>';
        echo     '<td>'.$row['BusinessEntityID'].'</td>';
        echo     '<td>'.$row['FirstName'].'</td></tr>';
    }
}
```